# Display my app icon in android contact list

Tags: android

Integrate my app icon with android Contact list, 
Display the **app icon** if the contact is associated with the application

Comment: Can you more explain ?

Comment: Your question does not contain a lot of information

Comment: Please Elaborate more

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21701017/display-the-app-icon-if-the-contact-is-associated-with-the-application-in-phone