# Showing app icon in contacts by updating contact in android

Tags: android, android-contacts, contactscontract, android-syncadapter, android-account

I wanted to add my app icon in the contacts app as Whatsapp or Skype does.

I have gone through some links and managed to add my add in accounts list of settings. Some of the links are [here](http://www.c99.org/2010/01/23/writing-an-android-sync-provider-part-1/),[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21701017/display-the-app-icon-if-the-contact-is-associated-with-the-application-in-phone) and [here](http://www.finalconcept.com.au/article/view/android-account-manager-step-by-step-2).

But i am not getting how particular contact will be updated with my app icon. I tried to play around in `performSync` `overriden` function. But did not help.

So my question is,

> I have list of phone numbers inside my app so how to update the contacts for those numbers only?

Comment: Did you find the solution? Please share if you got the solution. Thanks